# Python: comparing part of lines in two text files with different number of columns

Tags: python

I have two long text files (~50k lines) which are structured as follows:

```
time   index   length    a    b    c    ...
```

all of which are integers. 'length' tells me the amount of numbers (here labelled 'a', 'b', 'c', ...) that follow, which can be different for every row (and is also not equal for the same row in the two files). These numbers are sorted. Now, I need to find how many of the numbers 'a', 'b', 'c' that appear in line 1 of file 1 also appear in line 1 for file 2, and so on for the whole file. I have attempted this with Pandas but the variable number of columns gave me some troubles.

Answer (score 0):

Here's an idea :

- Get the first line of your file a
- Get the first line of your file b
- Create a list with the first line. Separate each items every spaces (" ") on both lists
- remove the first 3 items (time,index and length).
- For each item in your list of the file a, search it in the list of the file b
- Repeat for each lines in the file

This may help you :

```
filea = "C:\file\path\a.txt"
myfilea = open(filea, 'r')
data=myfilea.readlines()

fileb = "C:\file\path\a.txt"
myfileb = open(fileb, 'r')
datb=myfileb.readlines()

for ia in range (0,len(data)):
    linea = []
    lineb = []
    linea = data[ia].split()
    lineb = datb[ia].split()
    for x in range (0,len(linea)):
        if(linea[x] in lineb):
            print(str(linea[x])+" has been found")
```